# Polar coordinates boundaries: region in the plane bounded by circles $x^2 + y^2 = 4 $ and $ x^2 + y^2 = 9$, with $y \le\ 0$

Tags: calculus

When I draw it up, it is bounded in the 2nd and 3rd quadrant and that $$ 2 \le\ r \le\ 3 $$

The answer says that for $\theta$, $$ \pi \le\ \theta \le\ 2\pi $$

Can somebody explain why it isn't $$ \frac \pi 2 \le\ \theta \le\ \frac{3 \pi}{2} $$

Does this mean if the circles were bounded by $y\ge 0$, would it be $$ 0 \le \theta \le \pi? $$

Thank you!! Any more examples on $\theta$ boundaries would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y\geq 0$ would indeed be $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Remember that $y\leq 0$ denotes the lower half of the plane.

$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}$ would be $x\leq 0$.

Similarly, $x\geq 0$ is ( $0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and  $\frac{3\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ ).

Answer (score 0):

When $y<0$ we are in the third and fourth quadrants with $\theta$ between $ \pi, 2 \pi. $. If problem is given as $x<0$ what you said would have been correct.

and yes, $y>0$ has the radius vector confined to quadrants 1 and 2 with the angle bounds you mention.